# MySQL - cast columns to array and use IN statement on it

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table `Foo` like:

```
id,
bar_1,
bar_2,
bar_3
```

`bar1, bar2, bar3` could contain foreign key (integer) or `null`. I want to select all rows from `Foo`, where ids `2, 4` (both) are present in any two of `bar1, bar2, bar3`.

Simple way would be to make lot of `OR`'s, but I believe there's simplier way.

I thought about something like

`SELECT * FROM foo WHERE (2,4) IN ARRAY(bar_1, bar_2, bar_3)`

Is it possible?

Comment: what is bar_1? a number?

Comment: Integer. Updated the question

Comment: SELECT * FROM foo WHERE id in (2, 4) ?

Comment: You misunderstood my question. (2, 4) should be present in any subset of `bar_1, bar_2, bar_3`, for example `bar_1 = 2 and bar_2 = 4 or bar_1 = 4 and bar_2 = 2 or bar_1 = 4 and bar_3 = 2` and so on (cartesian)

Comment: ahh, I see now, bar_1, bar_2, bar_3 are columns, ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, almost :-)

```
SELECT * FROM foo 
WHERE 2 IN (bar_1, bar_2, bar_3)
  AND 4 IN (bar_1, bar_2, bar_3);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar_1 IN (2,4) OR bar_2 IN (2,4) OR bar_3 IN (2,4)
```

Comment: what if bar_1 = 2, bar_2 = 2 and bar_3 = 2?

Comment: both 2 and 4 should exists... in this case only 2 exists

Comment: uups, yes you right. @ThorstenKettner has the write answer isn't it

Answer (score 0):

I think..no.. use code like this

```
select * from foo where ((concat(bar_1,',',bar_2)='2,4') || (concat(bar_2,',',bar_3)='2,4') || (concat(bar_3,',',bar_1)='2,4') || (concat(bar_2,',',bar_1)='2,4') || (concat(bar_3,',',bar_2)='2,4') || (concat(bar_1,',',bar_3)='2,4'))
```

Comment: what if bar_1 = 4, bar_2 = 2 ?

Comment: Please check the query again..the condition has been concatenated as bar_2,',',bar_1='2,4'

Comment: if it fulfills the answer then ok... please explain mess by concatenation after that concatenation will be removed from MySQL

Comment: any reason to concat, and do additional operations, when you can just compare?